# How to simulate objectpointers

Tags: java, dll, jna

I hava a facade object for a dll that i cant modify using jna.
The dll keeps internal states and should always be the same instance.
The facade object keeps state aswell.

If I understand correctly, if i change a non-primitive of an object, that change will not traverse back to the caller since the internal pointer to that non-primitive might have changed.

Is there a better way then passing around a wrapperobject to keep all changes?
eg.:

```
public class Facade

{
    private final Dll dll;
    public Facade(int foo, int bar)
    {
        //init the Facade
        this.dll = new Dll();
    }
    int foo(int bar)
    {}
    // more methods
}

public class Wrapper
{
    public final Facade facade;

    public Wrapper(Facade facade)
    {
        this.facade = facade;
    }
}

public static class App
{
    public static int main(String[] args)
    {
        Facade fac = new Facade(0,0);
        Wrapper pointerSim = new Wrapper(fac);

        methodA(pointerSim);
        methodB(pointerSim);
    }
}
```

With the goal of  pointerSim reflecting the changes after methodA and B to Member classes and byte arrays.

Or is my pretense false?

Comment: JNA uses the `volatile` keyword to identify fields which may change on the native side (typically in another thread); it avoids writing those fields in its general synch methods (`read()/write()`) but the write can still be performed with `writeField()`.

Comment: You can also just use a generic `Pointer` (or your own `PointerType` so you have some type safety), and use the memory accessor methods to push/pull data only as needed.

Comment: @technomage can you expand on this a bit more please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass around native objects using a simple `Pointer`.  That class has a number of accessor methods to read offsets into memory from the base pointer.

If you want type safety around a specific class of pointers, you can make your own pointer type with

```
public class Facade extends PointerType { 
    public Facade() { }
    public Facade(Pointer p) { }
}
```